# Aplicação MVC + EF com N-Camadas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, engenharia-de-software

Estou trabalhando em um projeto MVC com EF 6, e estou tendo um problema bastante curioso, em algumas ViewModel, o objeto que vem do meu DbContext parece não persistir e recebo a genérica mensagem System.NullReferenceException.

O curioso que digo é porque isto ocorre em poucas camadas, já revisei meu mapeamento no DbContext, comparei com os que estão funcionando e não consigo encontrar uma possível causa do problema.

Este projeto tem diversas camadas, bem separadas:

> Software.Data
>
> Software.Domain
>
> Software.Services
>
> Software.Core
>
> Software.Web

Meu DbContext é inicializado no Core, então quando precisamos chamar algum método fazemos o seguinte:

> ProdutoCoreController produtoCore = new ProdutoCoreController();
>
> viewModelProdutos.Produto = produtoCore.RetornarProduto(id, IDLoja);

Algumas views funcionam normalmente, porem neste caso em particular quando passo para minha *Partial* o *Model* com os objetos já carregados, ele persisti dentro na partial mas na minha primeira chamada de output ele acusa o erro.

Alguém já teve o problema ou semelhante, o que eu poderia verificar a mais ou possa ter esquecido?

Comment: Qual a necessidade dessa separação?

Comment: O erro ocorre sempre nos mesmos ViewModel ? Seu Produto ViewModel não tem que instanciar algum objeto no create  dele ?

Comment: Sim, em duas ViewModel. No create dela eu instancio os objetos, inclusive em modo debug consigo ler todos os dados, mas quando chamo via razor uma determinada propriedade, ex. Produto.Nome, recebo a exception.

Comment: Resolvido o problema?